# Display deepest post category, when post have multiple categories

Tags: categories

I want to display the direct category ancestor of a given post. An illustrative example:

These are the categories I have:

```
 Cat1
 Cat2
  Cat2.1
   Cat2.1.1
   Cat2.1.2
  Cat2.2
   Cat2.2.1
   Cat2.2.2
  Cat2.3
 Cat3
  Cat3.1
   Cat3.1.1
 Cat4
```

I check the whole trailing, like in:

```
  Cat1
  [X]Cat2
    [X]Cat2.1
        Cat2.1.1
     [X]Cat2.1.2 <-my post
       Cat2.2
        Cat2.2.1
        Cat2.2.2
       Cat2.3
  [x]Cat3<
    [x]Cat3.1
     [x]Cat3.1.1 <-my post
     Cat4
```

So I have `'my post'` assigned to a multiple categories. Lets say I am navigating to `'my post'` like this : `Cat3->Cat3.1->Cat3.1.1->my post`. Now, in the single post page, I want to display the name of the direct category ancestor of `'my post'` (`Cat3.1.1` in this case). But the question is how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$ancestors_array = get_ancestors($category_id, 'category');
$very_first_ancestor_id = end($ancestors_array); // Cat3
$parent_id = reset($ancestors_array); // Cat3.1
```

See [Function Reference/get_ancestors](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors)

Comment: Yes but how to get this current category Cat3.1.1 id?

Comment: As I understand, `category ancestor of a given post` is not `post category`. So you should ask for `post category`. [Function Reference/get the category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category)

Comment: then I use `get_the_category` i get array of `my post` categories (Cat2,Cat2.1,Cat2.1.2,Cat3,Cat3.1,Cat3.1.1). But I as my user was navigating to 'my post' like this Cat3->Cat3.1->Cat3.1.1->my post , I need to get only current category (`Cat3.1.1` in this case)

Comment: Then the only way is to check the referrer.

Comment: I can check referrer, but what if user comes from outside to 'my post' not from inner pages of my site? So we can say wordpress doesn't fully support multiple categories for one page?

Comment: It does supports, but when the post exists in multiple categories it's impossible to guess which one of multiple categories do you mean at the moment. The only suggestion I have for your situation is to save meta data for each post with preferred category to show post in.